# SICP: Pascal's triangle problem

Tags: lisp

I was reading SICP and was solving a problem that asked to create a function in lisp for finding elements of Pascal's triangle.
The way I went about it is to take input as the row number and then print each element of the row iteratively, whose value would be found recursively.

```
(define (pascDisp n)
        (define i 1)
        
        (define (pasc n i)
                (if (or (= i 1)
                        (= i n))
                    1
                    (+ (pasc (- n 1)
                             (- i 1))
                       (pasc (- n 1)
                             i))))
        
        (define (pascDispIter n i)
                (display (pasc n i))
                (display " ")
                
                (if (<= i n)
                    (pascDispIter n
                                  (+ i 1))))
                              
        (pascDispIter n i))

(pascDisp 5)
```

This does print out all the elements however, it goes into an infinite loop. I can't seem to find any problem with the logic though. The interpreter shows that
`(pasc (- n 1) i)`
is being called infinitely. Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: Try changing `(<= i n)` to `(< i n)`.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus that would result in *not printing* of the last element of the row (i.e. 1).

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried it?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus apologies, you are right, it works and I've understood where I went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has an "off by one" mistake: in the $n$'th row, it prints $\binom{n}{1},\ldots,\binom{n}{n+1}$ (the condition `i <= n` should be corrected to `i < n`).

This highlights another problem with your code: it implicitly assumes that $1 \leq i \leq n$, which is not necessarily correct (and also has a wrong base case: it should be $\binom{n}{0} = 1$; indeed, $\binom{n}{1} = n$). Instead, you should first check whether $i$ is within bounds, and if not, output zero.

(This will not work with negative binomial coefficients, but you're probably not interested in those.)